# Python eval() syntax error when trying to evaluate an expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, eval

I am having trouble with the eval() Python function in this code:

```
 f = 'x'
 f = raw_input('f(x)=')

def ytest(y,x,f):
    if y >= eval(f)
        return 1
    else
        return 0
```

I know that eval() is a bad way to do this, but I am the only person who will ever be using my simple program. Whenever I try to run this I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Grant\Desktop\Plotter\plotter.py", line 9
    if y >= eval(f)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this causing an error? If f is a valid python expression in string form, shouldn't the code be valid?

the error also happens when I replace eval(f) with eval('0') so I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: you cannot have multiple statements for f. you either say f='x' or say f=raw_input('f(x)')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need colon at the end of `if` and `else` statements.

```
if y >= eval(f):
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

EDIT: Added [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) and `else`

Comment: and after the `else` too

Comment: Wow I feel stupid. Thank you for your quick reply.